# Select link inside div tag

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I would like to get a link (URL to be specific) inside a div class. This is the code I have that gets me the text inside div class (**Some text...**).

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='content']"))
{
    //saves text (node.InnerText) in array          
}
```

This is the HTML from the site. I would like to get **www.google.com**

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Some text... 
    <a href="www.google.com">LINK</a> 
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can find your answer on the link below:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087367/get-href-value-from-html-anchor-tag-c-sharp

Comment: @user1939593 Regex for this is *not* a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='novica']/p/a[@href='www.google.com']"))
{
    //saves text (node.InnerText) in array          
}
```

Comment: the xpath query is //div[@class='novica']/p/a[@href='www.google.com']

Answer (score 0):

That code is not valid based on your writing, however you have 2 options:

1. Once you have the node for the `div`, use `.GetElementsByTagName("a")` or the children to pull out the link, then get it's href attribute.
2. Amend your `SelectNodes()` XPath to get the `a` tag instead: `//div[@class='novica']/p/a`.

The first is obviously better if you *do* need the `.InnerText` of that element to get `Some text...`, however the second would be faaster.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='novica']"))
{
    var links = node.Descendants("a").Select(n => n.InnerText).ToList();
}
```